# query by reference sanity.io

Tags: next.js, sanity, groq

I have three schemas `docTopics` => `subTopics` => `article` that are references of each other.

I wanted to write a query for `docTopics` to return all the `subTopics` references to `docTopics`

```
export const queryRefrence = groq`
  {
    "topics": *[_type == "subTopics"] {
      _id,
      topic,
      title,
      id,
      "topics": docsTopics[] -> {title}
    }
  }`
```

Answer (score 1):

After some research from the documentation. I was able to nest the subtopics inside of topics

```
"mainTopics":*[_type == "docsTopics"] | order(title) {
    title,
  "subTopics" : *[_type == "subTopics" && topic._ref == ^._id] | order(id) {
      title,
      slug,
      id
    } 
  }
```